# Why is there a minus sign ($-$) , before the integral $\int_{S_2} M dx$?

Tags: vector-analysis

I am looking at the proof of the Green theorem.

[image]

$$S_1: y_1=f_1(x), a \leq x \leq b$$
$$S_2: y_2=f_2(x), a \leq x \leq b$$
$$\iint_R \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}=\int_{f_1(x)}^{f_2(x)} \int_a^b  \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}dxdy=\int_a^b \int_{f_1(x)}^{f_2(x)} \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} dy dx=\int_a^b [M(x,f_2(x))-M(x,f_1(x))]dx=\int_a^b M(x,f_2(x))-\int_a^b M(x,f_1(x)) dx$$

But...why is $\int_a^b M(x,f_2(x))-\int_a^b M(x,f_2(x)) dx$ equal to $-\int_{S_2} M dx- \int_{S_1} Mdx$ ??

Why is there a minus sign ($-$) , before the integral $\int_{S_2} M dx$??

Comment: Because you are going in the opposite direction along $S_2$.

Comment: But...according to my textbook, we find the sign like that:
$$$$
If I walk on the curve with the positive orientation,then the space $D$ should be always to my left. 
$$$$So,shouldn't both orientations at $S_1$ and $S_2$ be positive,in this case?

Or am I wrong?

Comment: OK but you have the limits in the integrals as $\int_a^b$ you need to change one to $\int_b^a$ for traversing $S_2$ in the proper direcion.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus A ok!!! I understand!!!Thank you very much!!!